# How to change Dreamweaver CS3's inbuilt spell checking English language US to UK?

Tags: windows-xp, spell-check, dreamweaver

How to change Dreamweaver CS3's inbuilt spell checking English language US to UK.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Yahoo! Answers:](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080525161408AAQXK2s)

- Press Ctrl + U
- Then go to Dictionary
- Change language to English (UK)

The settings screen should look something like this (Arabic example):

[image]